# How can i adjust the height on this part? HTML

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm completely new to HTML and I was trying to make a little project for myself so that I can learn a little bit more, but I wanted to ask something about how I can change the height of this text I'm trying to make it like Twitter and so that the tweets are separate from the others.

[So that the "tweets" are separate like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD76e.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My first web page!</title>
  <style>
    img {
      width: 66px;
      border-radius: 50px;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .username {
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="images/reyna.png" />
  <p class="username">@Reyna</p>
  <p>Yeni profil fotom nasıl?</p>

  <img src="images/killjoy.jpg" />
  <p class="username">@Killjoy</p>
  <p>Profil foton çok tatlı!</p>

  <img src="images/reyna.png" />
  <p class="username">@Reyna</p>
  <p>Teşşekür ederim seninkiside öyle!</p>

  <img src="images/reyna.png" />
  <p class="username">@Reyna</p>
  <p>Merhabaa! Jett bu gün çok üzgün :(</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, how do you know that separator according to your code?

Answer (score 0):

````
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>My first web page!</title>
      <style>
        img {
          width: 66px;
          border-radius: 50px;
          float: left;
          margin-right: 10px;
        }
        
        .chat {
            margin: 100px 0;
        }

        .username {
          font-weight: bold;
          margin-top: 30px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="chat">
          <img src="images/reyna.png" />
      <p class="username">@Reyna</p>
      <p>Yeni profil fotom nasıl?</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="chat">
      <img src="images/killjoy.jpg" />
      <p class="username">@Killjoy</p>
      <p>Profil foton çok tatlı!</p>
  </div>

      <div class="chat">
      <img src="images/reyna.png" />
      <p class="username">@Reyna</p>
      <p>Teşşekür ederim seninkiside öyle!</p>
  </div>

      <div class="chat">
      <img src="images/reyna.png" />
      <p class="username">@Reyna</p>
      <p>Merhabaa! Jett bu gün çok üzgün :(</p>
    </div>
    </body>
  </html> ```
````

create a div that contain image and text and
give some margin or you want the last message to take all the remaining space?

Comment: Hello i want it to be like this https://prnt.sc/ANvorKEpPGrH

Comment: hey, just group 3 into 1 div and give margin-bottom as you like probably 150px